# unity linux editor import mp3 raise error: Unspecified error during import of AudioClip

Tags: unity-game-engine

I google this problem but all solution is for windows, but I use unity linux editor, so I don't know how to fix it

err output:

```
Unspecified error during import of AudioClip Assets/Resources/Sound/footstep.mp3
```

[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WqNuhekBvVq0aJ8952Kwz71vHgRrsp4z) is my audio

[image]

here is my import settings
[image]

Comment: What importer settings are you using? Is this happening for all sounds or just that sound? Is that sound playable in an audio program? Is there any additional information in the Unity editor.log file?

Answer (score 0):

in short:

```
sudo apt install lib32stdc++6 -y
```

in detail:

this bug occurs for importing all audio files
I fix it, here is my solution in linux

unity editor console doesn't show any error reason,

**but in unity editor Editor.log, it show following**

```
Updating Assets/FOOTSTEP_Trainers_Asphalt_Run_RR8_mono.wav - GUID: 870800666a72341ff8b8cc38e0706141...
FSBTool: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
----- Compute hash for Assets/FOOTSTEP_Trainers_Asphalt_Run_RR8_mono.wav.
Unspecified error during import of AudioClip Assets/FOOTSTEP_Trainers_Asphalt_Run_RR8_mono.wav

(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Src/AssetPipeline/AudioImporter.cpp Line: 949)
```

so the solution is simple, since Editor.log show:

```
 FSBTool: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I google abvoe error, and find following solution

```
sudo apt install lib32stdc++6 -y
```